# Joining multiple select sql statements (4 tables)

Tags: mysql

I need to join together 2 SQL statements and both of those statements work on their own. But I don't know how to combine both into 1 SQL statement.

I have two tables in 1st statement, `TR120` and `TR1201`.

The SQL is this:

```
select 
    PRODUCT, PRICE, QUANTITY, INVOICE.DATE 
from 
    TR1201
left join 
    (select 
         DATE, ID as INVOICE_ID, INVOICE 
     from TR120) as INVOICE on INVOICE.INVOICE_ID = ID 
where 
    INVOICE.DATE >= '2016-06-01' and INVOICE.DATE <= '2016-06-30'
```

This returns a list of all the products I sold, with price, quantity and date of sales in a specific time frame from 01-06-16 till 30-06-16.

Now I need to find out the latest price that I bought product for in different two tables `TR100` and `TR1001` based on the product and date of sale from the 1st SQL statement.

```
select 
    PRODUCT, PRICE, SUP.DATE  
from 
    TR1001 
left join 
    (select 
         DATE, ID as SUP_ID, SUP_INVOICE 
     from TR100) as SUP on SUP.SUP_ID = ID
```

This returns a list of all the products that I have bought with a price and a date. I only need last record from this query based on product and date of purchased.

**TR120**

```
ID | INVOICE | DATE
1  | 000001  |2016-06-05
2  | 000002  |2016-06-15
3  | 000003  |2016-06-25
```

**TR1201**

```
ID | PRODUCT | PRICE A | QUANTITY
1  | A       | 2,00    |    5
2  | A       | 2,00    |    2
3  | A       | 2,00    |    1
```

**TR100**

```
ID | SUP_INVOICE | DATE
1  | 160001      | 2016-05-30
2  | 160002      | 2016-06-16
```

**TR1001**

```
ID | PRODUCT | PRICE B
1  | A       | 0,5
2  | A       | 0,7
```

The result I am trying to get is this:

```
PRODUCT | PRICE A (tr1201) | QUANTITY | DATE (tr100) | PRICE B (tr1001)
A       | 2                |  5       | 2016-05-30   |   0,5
A       | 2                |  2       | 2016-05-15   |   0,5
A       | 2                |  1       | 2016-05-16   |   0,7
```

That is all I want to do :(

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried first_value?

```
FIRST_VALUE ( [scalar_expression ] )   
    OVER ( [ partition_by_clause ] order_by_clause [ rows_range_clause ] )
```

it works like this:

```
  select distinct id, 
         first_value(price) over (partition by id (,sup) order by date DESC (latest, ASC for oldest)) as last_price
 from table;
```

Documentation can be found here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213018.aspx

Comment: Thank you aswell!!! I will try both examples and report back with results.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have your tables so cannot test and therefore am providing advice only.
I think what you need is an Outer apply like this instead of joins

```
select 
      T1.Product
    , T1.Price
    , T2.DATE   -- Alias this
    , T2.Price  -- Alias this
    , T3.DATE   -- Alias this
    , T3.Price  -- Alias this
from T1
OUTER APPLY (
    select top 1
          Date
         ,Price
    from table2
    WHERE ID = T1.Id AND product = T1.Product-- plus any other joins
    ORDER BY Date desc
) as T2 
OUTER APPLY (
    select top 1 
          Date
         ,Price
    from table3
    WHERE ID = T1.Id AND product = T1.Product-- plus any other joins
    ORDER BY Date desc
) as T3
```

Comment: Thank you. I will try it out!

Comment: Sorry HEKi. I have got this wrong. I use SQL Server and missed the MySQL tag on your post.

MySQL doesn't support CROSS APPLY

I was trying to be helpful but I apologise that I may have led you astray.